# Python Explicit FTP doesn't negotiate TLS

Tags: python, ssl, ftp

I'm trying to transfer a file to a host over FTP TLS explicit, but don't know how to handle the certificate.  A WinSCP log of the transaction shows that the TLS negotiation is handled and the certificate is verified.  But my Python script fails to do this.  I know the certificate fingerprint and the cipher, but don't know how to implement it.

My script:

```
import ftplib
import ssl


def main():
    ctx = ssl._create_stdlib_context(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ftps = ftplib.FTP_TLS(context=ctx)

    try:
        ftps.set_debuglevel(2)
        print(ftps.connect(host))
        ftps.auth()
        print(ftps.login(username,password))
        print("1")
        ftps.prot_p()
        print("2")
        #ftps.cwd('/')
        print("3")
        print (ftps.retrlines('LIST'))
        print("4")
        ftps.storbinary("STOR test.csv", open('C:\\test.csv', 'rb'))
        print("5")
    except Exception as ex:
        print("error: ")
        print(ex)

    ftps.close()

    input('Hit <ENTER> to close...')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my output, the last line is the Python error:

```
*get* '220 Microsoft FTP Service\n'
*resp* '220 Microsoft FTP Service'
220 Microsoft FTP Service
*cmd* 'AUTH TLS'
*put* 'AUTH TLS\r\n'
*get* '234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.\n'
*resp* '234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.'
*cmd* 'USER xxx'
*put* 'USER xxx\r\n'
*get* '331 Password required\n'
*resp* '331 Password required'
*cmd* 'PASS ********'
*put* 'PASS ********\r\n'
*get* '230 User logged in.\n'
*resp* '230 User logged in.'
230 User logged in.
1
*cmd* 'PBSZ 0'
*put* 'PBSZ 0\r\n'
*get* '200 PBSZ command successful.\n'
*resp* '200 PBSZ command successful.'
*cmd* 'PROT P'
*put* 'PROT P\r\n'
*get* '200 PROT command successful.\n'
*resp* '200 PROT command successful.'
2
3
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'
*get* '200 Type set to A.\n'
*resp* '200 Type set to A.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,4,4).\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,4,4).'
*cmd* 'LIST'
*put* 'LIST\r\n'
*get* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.\n'
*resp* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.'
*get* '226 Transfer complete.\n'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete.'
226 Transfer complete.
4
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*put* 'TYPE I\r\n'
*get* '200 Type set to I.\n'
*resp* '200 Type set to I.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,4,3).\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,4,3).'
*cmd* 'STOR test.csv'
*put* 'STOR test.csv\r\n'
*get* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.\n'
*resp* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.'
error: 
The read operation timed out
```

Comment: Please show any error messages you got.

Comment: I edited my post to include a log with the error.

Comment: According to the update there is no TLS negotiation problem at all as you claim. If there would be one you would not be able to even issue the USER command after AUTH TLS. The problem is instead a timeout of the data connection  during the second data transfer which might be caused by a firewall in between or some antivirus at the server or similar. But its not a TLS negotiation problem.

Comment: But if I log a WinSCP session I can see certificate validation taking place that doesn't appear to happen with my Python script.  I'll ask our security person, though, about the firewall.

Comment: Can't be a firewall issue, since the transfer works through WinSCP.

Comment: I have no idea what the real issue is but I can say for sure that it is unrelated to the TLS negotiation as you claim. Read timeout means that the server did not reply in the expected time which could be because of some AV at the server scanning the uploaded file. It might also be that WinSCP works because it waits longer for the server to reply.

Comment: Show us WinSCP log file + What is `x.x.x.x` part in the 227 response? Is it the IP address you are connecting to? Or different one?

Comment: I'm leaving out the address for security.  Yes, it's the correct address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the unwrapping of the socket after the file is transmitted.  More specifically, the shutdown() method appears to wait for the server to see if it's okay to close the socket.  In this case the server doesn't answer.  The file does indeed get transmitted, but the socket issue throws an error before a "File transfer complete" response can be received.

It seems to go like this (sending file to server):
1. Establish FTP TLS
2. Client issues STOR command
3. A secure socket is created
4. The file is transferred
5. The socket is unwrapped and disposed of.
6. The "transfer complete" response is received from the server.

But an issue with step 5 prevents 6 from happening.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.  A little bit of research shows that sockets can be closed instead of shutdown and that servers may not respond to socket shutdown requests.

My solution was to modify my local python libraries to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

> A WinSCP log of the transaction shows that the TLS negotiation is handled and the certificate is verified. But my Python script fails to do this. I know the certificate fingerprint and the cipher, but don't know how to implement it.

Your Python script does not fail in the TLS negotiation as you assume.

An upgrade from a plain connection to TLS is requested by the client with the `AUTH TLS` command which is accepted by the server which can be seen in the log:

```
*put* 'AUTH TLS\r\n'
*get* '234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.\n'
```

After that the TLS negotiation (i.e. TLS handshake) is done. If the handshake would fail the client would abort. But the handshake succeeds so that the client can continue with more command which also get accepted by the server:

```
*put* 'USER xxx\r\n'
*get* '331 Password required\n'
```

Thus, there is no problem in the TLS negotiation. It is also not a problem with the data transfer itself which can be seen in that the client succeeds in transferring data from the server, i.e. the directory listing:

```
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,4,4).\n'
*put* 'LIST\r\n'
*get* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.\n'
*get* '226 Transfer complete.\n'
```

It only fails when transferring a file to the server because the server does not reply within the expected time:

```
*put* 'STOR test.csv\r\n'
*get* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.\n'
error: 
The read operation timed out
```

It is unclear why the server fails to respond. One possible reason might be that the file needs to be processed by some application (like an antivirus) before the server will respond with success and that this processing takes too long.

Comment: Is there a workaround to this?  This seems strange, though, as a WinSCP transfer is done very quickly and the Python script takes a very long time before it times out.

Comment: I assume that it has to do with certificate validation, since the WinSCP log shows that taking place and the Python debug output does not.  That cert validation was what I was including as "TLS negotiation".

Comment: You might notice lots of other differences between the WinSCP log and the Python log. They log different things or log same things in a different way - and Python simply does not log that the TLS handshake takes place although it takes place. It also does not log how many data it transferred although it did transfer data.

Comment: *Is there a workaround to this?* - Since I don't know the cause of the original problem it is hard to say what a workaround might be. Did you transfer exactly the same file, into the same folder, to the same system as with WinSCP?

Comment: Yes.  Same file, same location, same system.

Comment: I can script the transfer through WinSCP, but I have to pass in the certificate fingerprint, which I'm not doing in the Python script...which is why I suspect there is something related to the certificate that has to be done in Python.

Comment: @Mike: very strange indeed then. But, there can be problems with some systems in between (firewall, router, IDS...) caused by specific packet sizes, false positives in the IDS triggered due to using or not doing session reuse and more. To narrow down the cause of the problem I would be to run the script at the server, then at a directly connected system etc and slowly move away until it fails.

Comment: @Mike: Python comes with its own CA store. If this is a certificate issued by a public CA then there is no need to add something special for validation. Short search suggest that WinSCP does not come with such a CA store and that you this need to accept any certificate by fingerprint. But, again there is no problem with TLS handshake here.

Comment: Can I assume that Python is indeed handling the server certificate behind the scenes?  Is there any way to verify that?  If I add some debug code to ftplib.py or ssl.py will that show up, or do these libraries have to be compiled somehow?

Comment: @Mike: I just realized that Python is not validating the server certificate properly with the context you use. The TLS handshake will still work but it will not complain about a bad certificate as WinSCP does. This makes the connection open to man in the middle attacks but is otherwise unrelated to your problem. You can verify that the TLS handshake was actually done by querying `ftps.sock.getpeercert(True)` which will gives you the DER presentation of the servers SSL certificate - which of course is only available if there was a TLS handshake.

Comment: Okay, I confirmed that there is a certificate.

Comment: Is this anything?...I noticed that my Python log has a "125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting." response from the server after the STOR command.  But the WinSCP log shows the data connection being closed and then reopened.  This response comes right after issuing the STOR command: "150 Opening BINARY mode data connection."

Comment: @Mike: hard to compare the logs from only this information - it might be more useful to get access to the WinSCP log too.

Comment: Okay, I found out that the file is indeed being transferred.  The "read operation timed out" might be something else.  Is Python attempting to read the directory immediately after the STOR transfer?  If so, that might be the cause of the time out.

Comment: @Mike: I would suggest that ftplib waits for the final reply from the server that the file was received but closes before the server has sent this reply.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that means ftplib should have a bug report.

Comment: @Mike:I don't think so. One might instead argue that the server should just reply faster. You might also try  if it helps to change the timeout parameter for FTP_TLS.

Comment: After checking the WinSCP log again, the timeout issue doesn't make sense.  WinSCP gets a "226 Transfer complete" response just 0.4 seconds after issuing the STOR command.  Python takes over 10 seconds to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**:
>   `ssl.create_default_context()` results in an error: "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]"

---

> [ssl.create_default_context(purpose=Purpose.SERVER_AUTH,  cafile=None, capath=None, cadata=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context)
>   Return a new SSLContext object with default settings for the given purpose.
>
> cafile, capath, cadata represent optional CA certificates to trust for certificate verification, as in SSLContext.load_verify_locations(). If all three are None, this function can choose to trust the system’s default CA certificates instead.

Use as follows:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context(Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
```

---

> **Question**: don't know how to handle the certificate

Use `ctx = ssl.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile=None, password=None)`,
you already have a `context=ctx`.

> [class ftplib.FTP_TLS(host=”, user=”, passwd=”, acct=”, keyfile=None, certfile=None, context=None, timeout=None, source_address=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS)
>
> A FTP subclass which adds TLS support to FTP as described in RFC 4217.
>   `context=` is a ssl.SSLContext object which allows bundling SSL configuration options, **certificates** and **private keys** into a single (potentially long-lived) structure.
>
> `keyfile=` and `certfile=` are a legacy alternative to context – they can point to PEM-formatted private key and certificate chain files (respectively) for the SSL connection.

---

> **Deprecated since version 3.6**:
>   **keyfile and certfile are deprecated** in favor of `context`. Please use [ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain) instead, or let ssl.create_default_context() select the system’s trusted CA certificates for you.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.  To be clear, though, I don't have a cert file...I'm validating the host's cert.

Comment: ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain() requires a certfile path, which I don't have...I'm not using a private certificate.

Comment: And calling ssl.create_default_context() results in an error: "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]"

Comment: @Mike: I see your Point and it has to be **PEM** Format. For now I don't know if it's possible to build a PEM Certificat from your available _"certificate fingerprint and the cipher"_.

Comment: If there would be a problem with the TLS handshake it would already fail in AUTH TLS. The logs show that it happily continues after that so it is not a TLS handshake problem - no matter what the OP claims.